# Stored procedure to give how many Qs answered and flagged within a section?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the following tables: `Section, Questions, Answers` and `QuestionFlagged`. The responses displayed for `reviewId=4`:

```
Section 1: User Info
      Question 1: What is your name?        Bob Smith
      Question 2: what is your occupation?  Engineer
      Question 3: Your favorite color?  
Section 1: User Location
      Question 1: What is your work location?  New York, NY
      Question 2: What is your office floor?  5th
      Question 3: your street address?  12 wolf street
```

I need to the following displayed (Need help with the sql):

```
Review: 4 | Section 1: User Info | 3 questions | 2 Completed | Flagged: Yes
```

My tables:

`Section`:

```
 SectionID int
 Title  nvarchar(50)
 Description nvarchar(2000)
```

`Question`:

```
 QuestionID int
 SectionID int
 QuestionText nvarchar(2000)
 Required boolean
 DisplayOrder int
```

`Response`:

```
ResponseID int
QuestionID int  
UserID int int
ReviewId int
AnswerValue nvarchar(1000)
```

`QuestionFlagged`:

```
FlaggedID int
QuestionID int
ReviewId int
UserId int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your response below, I've edited the query.  This should get you what you want I believe.

```
select  rsSectionAggregate.ReviewID, 
        rsSectionAggregate.SectionID, 
        Title, 
        QuestionCount, 
        QuestionsAnswered, 
        --Show whether there are flagged questions
        case 
            when QuestionsFlagged > 0 then 'Yes' 
            else 'No' 
        end as QuestionsFlagged
from 
(
    --first aggregate the results by section
    select r.ReviewID, rsSections.SectionID, Title, QuestionCount, COUNT(ResponseID) as QuestionsAnswered
    from
    (
        --this is done as a subquery so we know the total
        --number of questions for each section
        select s.SectionID, Title, COUNT(*) as QuestionCount
        from @Section s
        inner join @Question q on s.SectionID = q.SectionID
        group by s.SectionID, Title
    ) rsSections 
    inner join @Question q on rsSections.SectionID = q.SectionID
    left outer join @Response r on q.QuestionID = r.QuestionID
    group by r.ReviewID, rsSections.SectionID, Title,QuestionCount
) rsSectionAggregate
left outer join
(
    --here we determine if any questions are flagged for a given review
    --by counting them.
    select qf.ReviewID, COUNT(*) as QuestionsFlagged
    from @QuestionFlagged qf
    group by qf.ReviewId
) rsFlagged on rsFlagged.ReviewId = rsSectionAggregate.ReviewId
where rsSectionAggregate.ReviewID = 4
```

I was working with this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7447).

If you need the syntax for creating a stored procedure, I can edit that into the answer, but that's easily Googleable.

Comment: If a question (for reviewId=4) appears in the QuestionFlagged table..then it was flagged.

Comment: Bert, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @Chaka Modified the query to include flagged questions as I understand it.

Comment: Bert, you are awesome! Enjoy your holiday.

Comment: @Chaka Thanks, you too. Don't forget to vote or mark as correct answers that helped you out!